# Could not find com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:3.0.0

Tags: android, eclipse, android-gradle-plugin, dagger-2

I have imported project from Eclipse and I got so many errors and I resolved all of them now in the end after successful build, I'm getting error:

> Could not find com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:3.0.0

Code in `build.gradle(project)` is

```
    buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
}
```

and code in build.gradle(module:app) is

```
    android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.thanu.schoolbustracker"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 27
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile files('libs/google-play-services.jar')
    compile files('libs/maps.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:leanback-v17:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:exifinterface:27.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:3.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.databinding:library:3.1.2'
    compile 'com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.1.2'
    compile 'com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.2'
    compile 'com.android.databinding:adapters:3.1.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:15.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.3.0'
}
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { DependencyResolveDetails details ->
        def requested = details.requested
        if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
            if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
                details.useVersion '25.3.0'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After rebuild, project is built successfully but it is not creating APK and giving error;

> Could not find com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:3.0.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right now the latest version of Dagger is **2.15**, change this line:

```
annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.15'
```

Also other Dagger libraries are:

```
compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.15"
compile "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.15"
compile "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.15"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.15"
```

Comment: and what is this error I m getting Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

Comment: that is not an error, it's a warning. Recently (Since android studio 3 and new gradle wrapper) compile is replaced with implementation.

Comment: this is error I got  org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: Failed to capture snapshot of input files for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug' property 'annotationProcessorConfiguration' during up-to-date check.

Comment: @AdeepMalmotra I believe this a different error not related to dagger itself? I suggest edit the question changing the error or create a new question for that.

Comment: Okay.. thanks for your support, soon will update with new question.

Comment: this is link for my another question, please help me to find the solution of this problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50120440/org-gradle-api-uncheckedioexception